# Calculating BJT Base Resistor Value

Tags: transistors, bjt

The circuit below supplies 3.3V to an antenna (3.3VGreen), which then gives GNSS info to a control module (ANT_GNSS). The attached antenna is [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/398/AA.162.301111-1508634.pdf) and only consumes about 10mA
[image: Circuit]

I'd like to be able to switch the antenna on and off to preserve power, as this application uses a battery.  So I thought the circuit below would accomplish this.
[image: BJT circuit]

But I am wondering what resistor value I need at the BJT's base to bring the transistor to saturation?  The transistor's datasheet is linked here [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/ds30036-41708.pdf).  I am thinking that if h_fe is 100 @10mA (collector current) then base current needs to be at least 10mA/100 or 0.1mA to drive to saturation?  Following this [BJT Tutorial](https://www.circuitcrush.com/how-bjt-works/), but I have no practical experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere around 0.5 to 1mA is fine, forced beta of 10-20. The transistor is specified at a Ic/Ib = 10, but 20 will be fine too, especially at only 1mA Ic.

[image]

So the resistor would be about (3.3V - 0.7V)/0.75mA  or about 3.3K\$\Omega\$.

The hFE is specified at Vce = 1.0V and you would like it to be more like 0.1V to minimize the losses in the transistor.

You could also use an inexpensive logic-level p-channel MOSFET such as [AO3401A](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3401A.pdf) which will have negligible voltage drop.

Comment: What does it mean that the h_Fe was specified at 1V?  Could someone give an example of when this h_Fe would apply

Comment: For example an amplifier with the transistor biased around Vcc/2 rather than used as a switch (your application).